# Lable and button in the header section view UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, sectionheader

I am trying to add a section title Label and a button in the header section view. but it looks empty. when I run the application the header is empty. the 2nd section code work fine

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if (section == 0){
            let label = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 17, y: 139, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 45))
                       label.textColor = UIColor.black
                       label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
                       label.textAlignment = .left
                       label.text = "   My Balances"
                       label.backgroundColor  = UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1.00)
                       
                       let frame = tableView.frame
                       let height:CGFloat = 66

                       let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 306, y: 139, width: 15, height: 15))  // create button
                       button.tag = section
                       // the button is image - set image
                       button.setImage(UIImage(named: "remove_button"), for: .normal)

                       let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: height))  // create custom view
                       headerView.addSubview(button)   // add the button to the view
                       headerView.addSubview(label)
                       return headerView
                       //return label
                       
            //return label
            
        }
        else {
             let label = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 241, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 45))
            label.textColor = UIColor.black
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
            label.textAlignment = .left
            label.text = "   My Customers"
            label.backgroundColor  = UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1.00)
            
            return label
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. Label Y should be 0
2. headerView height should not be equal to tableViewHeight. Change it to your header view height.

Comment: Set height for header for section to your required height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not following the proper way. First you have to set height of header view using `heightForHeaderInSection` from tableview object in `viewDidLoad()` like -

```
tableView.heightForHeaderInSection = 250
```

or by using its delegate method -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 250
    }
```

You set the height of header view equal to tableview height. Set it less than it `let height:CGFloat = 250` -

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        
            let label = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 241, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 45))
            label.textColor = UIColor.black
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
            label.textAlignment = .left
            label.text = "   My Balances"
            label.backgroundColor  = UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1.00)
            
            let frame = tableView.frame
            let height:CGFloat = 250 

            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 10, width: 15, height: 15))  // create button
            button.tag = section
            // the button is image - set image
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "remove_button"), for: .normal)

            let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: height))  // create custom view
            headerView.addSubview(button)   // add the button to the view
            headerView.addSubview(label)
            return headerView
            //return label
            
        }
```

Or another way is to make custom reusable header view, register as header view and finally dequeu it.

You can follow the documentation from apple for second way - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views/adding_headers_and_footers_to_table_sections

Comment: Also fix the y position of the frame of UILabel and UIButton. Can you share your full code?

Comment: so you are not giving the height of headerView?